# jQuery: If class exists, remove it, then add it to new element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm working on an accordion style video section. I'm currently trying to check if a class exists on click. I want it to only open 1 section at a time, so I need to

1. Check if the class exists on click
2. If it does, remove class
3. Add class to the clicked element

I tried doing this with just `addClass();` and `toggleClass();` but am not 100% sure on what I'm missing.

**Add Class**

```
$(".contents-row").click(function(){
    $(this).toggleClass("content-open");
});
```

**Toggle Class**

```
$('.contents-row').click(function(){
    $(this).toggleClass('content-open');
});
```

**This is the basic HTML set up**

```
<div class="contents-row">
    <div class="content-option press">
        <div class="class-section-title">test1</div>
    </div>
    <div class="drop">
        test 1
    </div>
</div>
```

A full version of the drop down in on **[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7e6bknyr/3/)**.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/7e6bknyr/4/

Comment: I feel you should use `hasClass()` as per your requirement

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First remove `content-open` class from all elements having `content-open` class. Then add the class to clicked element like following.

```
$('.contents-row').click(function(){
    $('.content-open').removeClass('content-open');
    $(this).addClass('content-open');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the class `content-open` from all `div` with class  `contents-row` first and then add to the currently clicked `div`.

```
$('.contents-row').click(function(){
    $('.contents-row').removeClass('content-open');
    $(this).toggleClass('content-open');
});
```